# Finding the Column Index for a Specific Value

Tags: r, string

I am having a brain cramp.  Below is a toy dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
        id = 1:6, 
        v1 = c("a", "a", "c", NA, "g", "h"),
        v2 = c("z", "y", "a", NA, "a", "g"),
        stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I have a specific value that I want to find across a set of defined columns and I want to identify the position it is located in.  The fields I am searching are characters and the trick is that the value I am looking for might not exist.  In addition, null strings are also present in the dataset.

Assuming I knew how to do this, the variable *position* indicates the values I would like returned.

```
> df
  id   v1   v2 position
1  1    a    z        1
2  2    a    y        1
3  3    c    a        2
4  4 <NA> <NA>       99
5  5    g    a        2
6  6    h    g       99
```

The general rule is that I want to find the position of value "a", and if it is not located or if v1 is missing, then I want 99 returned.

In this instance, I am searching across v1 and v2, but in reality, I have 10 different variables. It is also worth noting that the value I am searching for can only exist once across the 10 variables.

What is the best way to generate this recode?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `match`:

```
> df$position <- apply(df,1,function(x) match('a',x[-1], nomatch=99 ))
> df
  id   v1   v2 position
1  1    a    z        1
2  2    a    y        1
3  3    c    a        2
4  4 <NA> <NA>       99
5  5    g    a        2
6  6    h    g       99
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks.  I really have to learn to use the apply functions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, drop the first column:

```
df <- df[, -1]
```

Then, do something like this (disclaimer: I'm feeling terribly sleepy<sup>*</sup>):

```
( df$result <- unlist(lapply(apply(df, 1, grep, pattern = "a"), function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, 99, x))) )
    v1   v2 result
1    a    z      1
2    a    y      1
3    c    a      2
4 <NA> <NA>     99
5    g    a      2
6    h    g     99
```

*** sleepy** = code is not vectorised

**EDIT** (slightly different solution, I still feel sleepy):

```
df$result <- rapply(apply(df, 1, grep, pattern = "a"), function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 0, 99, x))
```